# how to have template helpers change dynamically? backbone.js

Tags: templates, view, backbone.js, model, render

I have a template helpers method in my view like so:

```
    templateHelpers() {
    
    return {
        url : this.model.get('url')
    };
}
```

And I use the url variable in my template; However, the URL only gets assigned on button click; So when the view is rendered, the URL variable is initially undefined. How can I make it so that when the url is actually assigned, the template helper variable also updates to the updated url variable?

Answer (score 0):

You say that url is only assigned on button click and you want that template helper updates to the updated url when it is assigned.

So, the solution is simple if I understand you correctly:

1. Change template helper function definition and accept url as an argument.
2. Go to the function where you handle button click event.
3. Call template helper function with the updated url.
4. Use that url in the template helper function.